# Parallelize rfcv() function for feature selection in randomForest package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest, feature-selection

I wonder if anyone knows how to parallelize **rfcv()** function implemented in R-package ['randomForest'](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html). Sorry if the question sounds very basic, but I tried to do this using ['foreach'](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) without any results.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/package=caret) package and its documentation.

It not only is more general (allowing for more models than "just" random forests) but also integrates pre- and post-processing --- while also giving you parallel execution where feasible, particularly for evaluation and cross-validation which is an "embarassingly parallel" problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for this @Dirk. Now I managed to try filtering and recursive feature elimination functions in 'caret'. But I was also wandering whether there is an opportunity to parallelize rfcv() using for example mclapply (from 'multicore'). I am asking because 'multicore' is available on the r-cloud I am currently working on, whereas doMC does not work well for some reasons...